# Syntax completion based on snippets for rails project in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I wonder if exists some plugin which offers syntax completion based on rails snippets (from snipmate).
Example:

Being on specs, I provide `shou`, press hotkey and I got list of possible completions (like for Ctrl-p). Selecting anything from list, will insert a snippet.

Does something like this exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit `<C-r><Tab>` in *insert* mode to pop up a list of available snippets, hit `<Enter>` to select the right one and hit `<Tab>` to expand the snippet. But the menu doesn't provide a description.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to SnipMate, but you might also find Vim's line completion feature useful here.  While in insert mode, <kbd>Ctl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctl-l</kbd> will offer possible completions for the whole line.  So if you already have something like the following in your open buffers:

```
it { should belong_to(:user) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
```

and you start typing

`it {`<kbd>Ctl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctl-l</kbd>

... you will get a list of possible full line completions to match.